# streaming video from http address

Tags: http, http-live-streaming

I am trying to add an HTML div object to play a video that is being streamed...

it is being streamed over an address that is styled like this--

```
http://(ipaddress)/(videoname).m3u8
```

can I not play this from a video tag? I tried it in firefox and got this error-

```
HTTP “Content-Type” of “application/vnd.apple.mpegurl” is not supported. Load of media 
    resource http://172.30.204.207/live/sgsports/index.m3u8 failed.  
Cannot play media. No decoders for requested formats: application/vnd.apple.mpegurl
```

does anyone know what methods I can use to get this to work?

do i need to use HLS?

Comment: HLS is not supported natively on all browsers, you need a HLS player